# How to download and unzip a raster zipped file directly in r from github

Tags: r, github, raster

I am trying to download 'Landsat.rar` file (included 6 Landsat bands) and unzip it directly in r, but It doesn't work as I expected. Thank you for your help!

```
library(raster)

ls_url<-"https://github.com/tuyenhavan/Landsat-Data/blob/LS7/Landsat.rar"

temp<-tempfile()

download.file(ls_url,temp)

unzip(temp,"tif$")

myls<-stack("tif$")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How download and unzip raster data (Landsat) in r directly from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926076/how-download-and-unzip-raster-data-landsat-in-r-directly-from-github)

Answer (score 2):

Especially if you are using Windows, it might be that you need to use the binary mode in `download.file`:

```
download.file(ls_url, temp, mode="wb")
```

otherwise the file gets corrupted.

Also, the URL you are using is incorrect. You used the one for the web interface. If you want to get the file itself you need to use (check the link associated with the "Download" button):

```
https://github.com/tuyenhavan/Landsat-Data/raw/LS7/Landsat.rar
```

Finally, `unzip()` doesn't know how to deal with `rar` archive files. If you created this archive yourself, use the zip format instead; or unrar the file with another program (that you could call from R using `system()`).

Comment: I am so sorry that your code does not work. Can you write a complete code for this? thank you

Comment: @Tuyen I added some more info to my answer, hope it helps.